# How to read an EBCDIC file and find and replace Hex value x'BE

Tags: datastage, ebcdic

How do I read an EBCDIC file and find and replace Hex value x'BE?

I have an EBCDIC file coming from z/OS and landing on Linux.  This file is peppered with single smart quotes, x'BE.  I want to replace x'BE with x'7D, which is the standard single quote.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed 'y/\xbe/\x7d/' input-file > output-file
```

Comment: Thanks to you both.  I was hoping for DataStage solution.